# Передача данных в расширении Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular

Вообщем пишу расширение для Google Chrome в основе лежит angular, и есть 2 отдельный файла contentPage.js и backgroundPage.js, ну точнее они ts, а потом конвертируется, но это не важно. Вообщем я в contentPage полчаю сообщение с сайта, что пользователь авторизировался, после это я беру данные и localStorage куда их записал сайт, после мне необходимо, отправить эти данные обратно, в angular, но вопрос как??
Я читал что можно с помощью post.postMessage, но так только общение между contentPage и backgroundPage, и самое главное как это всё дело принять именно в angular??

Вот код из contentPage:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
   if (event.source != window) {
       return;
   }

   if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == 'LoginSuccess') && (event.origin == 'http://localhost:4200')) {
       let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
       let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
       console.log('Token: ' + token);
       console.log('User: ' + user);
  }

  if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == 'Logout') && (event.origin == 'http://localhost:4200')) {
      console.log('User Logout');
  }
});
```

Вообещем везде где я вывожу консольк мне нужно отсылать данные в anglar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё я нашел как отправлять данные в contentPage пишем:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'siteLogout' });
```

А в ангуляр компоненте пишем:

```
constructor() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    console.log(message);
  });
}
```